# Error output in data flow destination task

Tags: ssis

I want to create an error output in OLEDB destination task A and redirect all error rows to a new destination B. Presently, I am unable to do so since I can't seem to see any error output columns after I connect the red line from A to B even though all columns are present in A. i just get an empty disabled

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have you redirect the error rows (instead of default fail)?
See http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/23-How-to-handle-Failed-Rows-in-a-Data-Flow.html
[image]